# variables in bash

Tags: bash

```
for i in *.jpg
do
    j = '$i | cut -d . -f 1'
    convert $i $j".png"
done
```

temp.sh: line 3: j: command not found

I know about mogrify, just wanted to know how to get variables done in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the spaces around `=`:

```
for i in *.jpg
do
    j=`echo $i | cut -d . -f 1`
    convert $i $j".png"
done
```

Comment: Also, j should've been j=`echo $i | cut -d . -f 1`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I oversaw this. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Shabeer: If you need to use backticks in a comment, prefix these with a backslash (\\) as in `j=\`echo $i | cut -d . -f 1\``.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use bash's builtin [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the first dot and everything after it: `j="${i%%.*}"`

If you want to remove the *last* dot and anything following it (i.e. the file's extension), use: `j="${i%.*}"`

Example:

```
$ i="file.with.dots.ext"
$ echo "${i%%.*}"
file
$ echo "${i%.*}"
file.with.dots
```

Comment: And that's probably what he really wants. So `for f in ./*.jpg; do convert "$f" "${f%.*}.png"; done`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, your script won't work as expected if any filename contains any special character (such as a space). You should get in the habit of always enclosing variable references in double quotes. Try this:

```
for i in *.jpg
do
    j="$(echo "$i" | cut -d . -f 1)"
    convert "$i" "${j}.png"
done
```

Comment: That will throw an error, unless `$i` happens to hold a command name.

Comment: Yes, it's buggy code in ways beyond the double quotes. I see now that the original reply has been edited to include backticks. So, now I have a better idea of what the OP wanted. Without those backticks, the code is incomprehensible, at least to me. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating [bash parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) expansion and [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) for files with special characters in their names, and the code simplifies too:

```
for f in *.jpg; do 
    convert "$f" "${f%.*}.png"
done
```